# using modals in meteor templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have modal.html:

```
    <template name="modal">
      <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h2 class="modal-title">Dialog</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>
                Dialogs are typically used to prompt users to make a specific decision
                as part of or before continuing with a task or process. They can be used
                to inform users about a specific issue, to confirm particularly important
                actions, or to explain significant ramifications of an action before
                allowing the user to proceed.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-flat pull-left">More info...</button>
              <button class="btn btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

and I have transfer.html and transfer.js

```
<template name="transfer">
  <!-- Somewhere inside  template --> 
  <a href="#" class="btn small-btn btn-fab reminder-btn" id="lock-pay" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="foo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></a>
</template>

Template.transfer.events({
  'click #lock-pay': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').modal('show');
  }
})
```

I tried to have the modal template inside the same file as my transfer but that didn't work either

Comment: I've written a package making it easy to use bootstrap 3 modals. Feel free to [use it](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) or [read the code](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to actually render the modal template somewhere in your HTML, try this :

```
<template name="transfer">
  {{> modal}}
  <a href="#" class="btn small-btn btn-fab reminder-btn" id="lock-pay" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="foo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></a>
</template>
```

You need to assign an id to the modal div if you want to reference it using `#` :

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
  ...
</div>
```

You should use `data-toggle` along with `data-target` to open a modal instead of managing the click event yourself.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"></a>
```

Comment: Please add your modal code to further diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks! can i have multiple 'data-toggle's ie: data-toggle="tooltip modal"?